# What is the purpose of IO Streams in Java?

Tags: java, io

Please explain the use of Java's `InputStream` and `OutputStream` classes. I'm confused.

Comment: use google for this!! You will get tons of info!

Comment: There are for reading and writing binary data. If you want to read/write text I suggest you use Reader/Writer classes.

Comment: Confused about what? What part of the extensive Javadoc didn't you understand? What have you read so far? What's your question?

Comment: @EJP:actually there is many reader and writer class and also printwriter class in java,i didn't get hte uses of these things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of InputStream and OutputStream is to abstract different ways to input and output: whether the stream is a file, a web page, or the screen shouldn't matter. All that matters is that you receive information from the stream (or send information into that stream.)

**InputStream** is used for many things that you read from.

**OutputStream** is used for many things that you write to.

Comment: so what about ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStreams etc?

Comment: @thiyagu: These two Streams are used for reading and writing the streams in the form of Bytes..

Answer (score 3):

You can't get better explanation than [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html).

Summary:

[InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html): The abstract class; superclass of all classes representing an input stream of bytes.

[image]

[OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html): This abstract class is the superclass of all classes representing an output stream of bytes. An output stream accepts output bytes and sends them to some sink.

[image]

Some more details are available [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/io/index.html).

To know about Character Streams, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013996/byte-stream-and-character-stream) and [here](http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/post1.0/converting/convertingIO.html).

Comment: don't get mistaking tensed?friend....what is reader and writer class?

Comment: These are character streams. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013996/byte-stream-and-character-stream

Answer (score -1):

An I/O Stream represents an input source or an output destination. A stream can represent many different kinds of sources and destinations, including disk files, devices, other programs, and memory arrays.

Comment: Nice copy and paste from the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html)